# Matplotlib, two surfaces with same specified color are not the same?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm plotting things on a plane and a sphere from a simulation. However, the surface of the plane and the sphere are not showing up as the same color. Here is a minimal working example

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

u = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)
v = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 100)
x = 100 * np.outer(np.cos(u), np.sin(v))
y = 100 * np.outer(np.sin(u), np.sin(v))
z = 100 * np.outer(np.ones(np.size(u)), np.cos(v))

xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(50-40, 50+40, num=5), np.linspace(-40, 40, num=5))
zz = 0*xx

fig = plt.figure(figsize=plt.figaspect(1))

ax=fig.add_subplot(2,1,1, projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(x, y, z, color='r')

ax.set_xlim3d(-15, 15)
ax.set_ylim3d(-15, 15)
ax.set_zlim3d(90, 120)
ax.view_init(elev=20., azim=-90)
ax.set_axis_off()

ax=fig.add_subplot(2,1,2, projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(xx, yy, zz, color='r')

ax.set_xlim3d(-15+45, 15+45)
ax.set_ylim3d(-15, 15)
ax.set_zlim3d(-5, 25)
ax.view_init(elev=20., azim=-90)
ax.set_axis_off()

plt.show()
```

Any ideas why it isn't the same color and how to make it the same?

Comment: This would be an excellent place to upload a picture of your figure.

Comment: Looks like there is some shadows being simulated here.

Comment: Indeed, put `shade=False`.